# How to make UI adjust the length and width according to the size of the text?

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

I have done localization of my app. The problem that I'm facing is that, a single line of text may be 2 lines in chinese or some other language. It would be easier if the text blocks or buttons would increase the size according to the size of the text.
Is there any way out for this? Else I would have to fix the length and width to the maximum used by the language, but then some languages may not use up so much space and it will look odd.

Alfah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using fixed width / height, it is better to create a layout which allows the TextBlock to adjust its width. For example, if you have a two column layout, setting the column widths to Auto will cause the column to grow to accomodate its widest element:

```
<Grid Width="200">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="This is a label:"/>
    <TextBox Text="This is a value" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Grid does not meet my requirement so, most of the textblocks are in a canvas layout. So how do i?

Comment: You cannot do it in a canvas. What layout do you want to achieve? Canvas is not a good way to layout your UI!

Comment: well :) the UIelements cannot be put into row and column, It is manually fixed at specific postions for all the pages.

Comment: Well that's horrible Front-End work. Using absolute values in a Canvas will NEVER WORK

Comment: Actually in WP7 UI is designed in a such a way, phone UI also clips the string which crosses particular size, you can check in Zune Music by using long length name Song or Album.

Comment: I found Auto option for width and length in Blend. So if I set width and length to Auto for all UI, will it solve?